# Increase max line length for coffeelint in vim (mvim) when editing coffee files

Tags: vim, syntax, coffeescript, dotfiles

When I edit any `.coffee` file in my `mvim` and try to save that file with any line longer than 80 symbols, I get such error.

```
file_name.coffee |18 error| Line exceeds maximum allowed length Length is 91, max is 80.
```

This is extremely annoying, especially taking into consideration that we have convention of max 100 symbols per line in our company and even code of other team members causes problems for me locally.

The only place where I can change this limit is in `nodejs` module in file `.../node_modules/coffeelint/lib/coffeelint.js`, which has such line:

```
max_line_length: {
   value: 80,
   -level: ERROR,
   +level: IGNORE,
   message: 'Line exceeds maximum allowed length'
 },
```

But, of course, editing sources of `nodejs` libraries is not a good option.

In my `mvim` I use these `dotfiles` - https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles

In my project directory I have `.coffeelint.json`, but it does not work, however, it seems to contain needed and valid code for that (it works perfectly on TravisCI and on machines of other team members).

Questions:

1. Is there any place where I can turn off `coffeelint` call when saving file?
2. Is there any place where I can configure my `coffelint` max allowed line length?

Update:

Putting properly named (`.coffeelint.json`) config file into home directory helps, but is not proper solution in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all project parts (5 different repos now) we currently have `.coffeelint.json` file, that is not the proper name for `coffeelint`, if you want it to pick config file automatically. Current `.coffeelint.json` is used on TravisCI when checking code and is invoked with `-f` option,  as it turned out. So I my case I have two ways to fix weird behaviour (that is intended behaviour, actually):

1. Copy one of the configs from 5 related repos to `~/coffeelint.json`, so that `coffeelint` will use it automatically when vim will check file on save (but this will not do if some repos will have different configs, however, this solution does not require any changes to repos).
2. Create copy of each config file in each repository (so I'll have both `.coffeelint.json` and `coffeelint.json` in each repo) and add the newly added one to `.gitignore`, so that team members will not see it in their editors. This option is also inappropriate and looks ugly, cause I have to add 5 changes and 5 commits.

It seems that guys from the team decided to name `coffeelint` config file not properly in order to `hide it visually in code editors`. Solution cost me nerves, so, probably, I'll reconfigure everything properly and will rename configs to default names.

It would be nice if `coffeelint` supported multiple config files with levels of priority, but this is not possible now.

Answer (score 2):

It seems it is more a coffeelint question than a Vim question.

From http://www.coffeelint.org/#options :

It seems you have to generate a configuration file, tweaking the following option.

> max_line_length   This rule imposes a maximum line length on your code.
>   Python's style guide does a good job explaining why you might want to
>   limit the length of your lines, though this is a matter of taste.
>   Lines can be no longer than eighty characters by default.
>
> default level: error

It also seems you have to call coffeelint with your configuration file:

From : http://www.coffeelint.org/#usage

> coffeelint -f coffeelint.json application.coffee

You probably have to find in your dotfile where the coffeelint invocation is done, and add the configuration file with the -f option there.

Comment: I've read that before posting question. I my case it really looks like more Vim problem, cause all config files are present, but it seems that Vim somehow bypasses that config and uses default settings.

Comment: are sure that vim is invoking coffeelint with the -f option ? If you grep, coffeelint in the dotfiles you should have an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to pass the config file explicitly. Here are the [user docs](https://github.com/clutchski/coffeelint/blob/master/doc/user.md) for CoffeeLint. You should either create a `~/coffeelint.json` file or create a `coffeelint.json` in the root of your project.

Comment: I did that, as I've written above, but result was the same.

Comment: Have you tried just running CoffeeLint from the commandline? I've been maintaining the project for 2 years and sometimes plugin authors intentionally bypass CoffeeLint's config loader.

Comment: Yes, it seems I simply did mistake in filename when told that `~/coffeelint.json` does not work (it works and I simply mistyped file name).